# Error in wilcox.test.formula(x ~ group, data = df) : grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this and a hundred more columns like this

```
Group   V1  V2  V3
1   NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN
1   0.12611 10.75   NaN
1   NaN NaN 1.9909
1   0.085867    12.323  2.0125
1   NaN NaN 2.3301
1   NaN NaN NaN
2   0.0574  3.827   NaN
2   0.15607 1.1194  NaN
2   NaN 0.81006 0.77779
2   0.0737  0.35366 NaN
2   0.1265  2.4674  0.82335
2   0.097067    NaN 0.90923
2   0.82887 1.8804  0.96405
```

when I try to wilcox.test for each column it works 
`wilcox.test(V1 ~ Group, data = df)`

however if I try to make apply like this 
`wilcox <- apply(df[,-1], 2, function(x) wilcox.test(x ~ Group, data = df))`
it gives the error:

```
Error in wilcox.test.formula(x ~ Group, data = df) : 
grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

Anybody has any idea whats wrong?

Comment: The example you provided didn't show the error message.

Answer (score 0):

We need to create a `if/else` condition for those cases that have less number of elements.  Assuming that it is because of the missing values

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df[-1] %>% 
    map(~ tibble(.x, Group = df$Group)) %>%
    map(~ if(sum(!is.na(.$.x))>2 | nrow(.x) > 2) 
             broom::tidy(wilcox.test(.x~Group, data = .) ) else NA)
```

---

Using the same approach with the OP's code

```
apply(df[,-1], 2, function(x) if(sum(!is.na(x)) >2 ) 
                     wilcox.test(x ~ Group, data = df) else NA)
```

Comment: Thank you. As you guessed the problem was the NA values. I recognized one of the columns was full of NAs without any representative data. So thats why the R telling that I need exactly 2 levels since one is missing. So solved that way.